# Obtener valor de control DropdownList en Gridview

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Estoy presentando un pequeño inconveniente al momento de tratar de obtener un valor de un control dropdownlist

Tengo los siguientes escenarios

> 1. Creo mi control de lista y lo alimento mediante de esta manera

```
<tr>
                         <td style="width: 382px">BODEGA DE RETORNO</td>
                         <td>
                             <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListBodega" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="146px">
                             </asp:DropDownList>
                         </td>
                      </tr>
```

codebehind

```
Usuario UsuSession = (Usuario)Session["USUARIO_SESSION"];
var obtenerUsuario = db.usuarios.Where(u => u.id_usuario == UsuSession.IdUsuario);
                var objusuario = obtenerUsuario.FirstOrDefault();

                var obtenerBodegas = modelo.bodega.Where(b => b.id_municipio == objusuario.id_municipio);
                var bodega = obtenerBodegas.ToList();
                DropDownListBodega.DataSource = bodega;
                DropDownListBodega.DataTextField = "Nombre";
                DropDownListBodega.DataValueField = "id_bodega";
                DropDownListBodega.DataBind();
                DropDownListBodega.Items.Insert(0, "Select");
```

hasta aqui funciona normal. Obtengo los valores en la lista que deseo

> 2. Tengo un DataGrid en el cual muestro un conjunto de datos con los cuales pretendo realizar una accion con cada uno de ellos, la alimento mediante query

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewDatos" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" DataKeyNames="id_factura,id_detalle_factura,id_factura_articulo" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="id_factura_articulo" HeaderText="Id Factura Articulo" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="id_factura" HeaderText="ID Factura" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="id_detalle_factura" HeaderText="Detalle Factura" /> 
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="nombre_articulo" HeaderText="Nombre Articulo" /> 
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="nombre_bodega" HeaderText="Bodega" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="serial" HeaderText="Serial" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="codigobarras" HeaderText="Código Barras" />
                            <asp:HyperLinkField Text="Devolver" DataNavigateUrlFields="id_factura,id_detalle_factura,id_factura_articulo" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="DetalleDevolucion.aspx?idFactura={0}&idDetalle={1}&id_factura_articulo={2}&proceso=Devolver" /> 
                        </Columns>
                        <EmptyDataTemplate>
                            No se encontraron datos
                        </EmptyDataTemplate>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

codebehind

```
decimal idFactura = Convert.ToDecimal(factura.id_factura);
            System.Text.StringBuilder sql = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sql.Append("SELECT fa.id_factura_articulo, df.id_factura,fa.id_detalle_factura,ar.nombre as nombre_articulo, fa.serie as serial,bd.nombre as nombre_bodega,ar.codigobarras FROM factura_articulo fa ");
            sql.Append("INNER JOIN detalle_factura df ON fa.id_detalle_factura = df.id_detalle_factura ");
            sql.Append("INNER JOIN bodega bd ON bd.id_bodega = df.id_bodega ");
            sql.Append("INNER JOIN articulo ar ON ar.articuloid = fa.id_articulo  ");
            sql.Append("WHERE fa.id_factura = @p0 ");

            var registros = db.Database.SqlQuery<FacturaArticulo>(sql.ToString(), idFactura).ToList();

            GridViewDatos.DataSource = registros;

            GridViewDatos.DataBind();
```

En el dataGrid tengo un control tipo `HyperLinkField` con el cual al dar clic en un registro pretendo realizar acciones con el mismo

Todo lo anterior me muestra los datos tal y como los quiero ver

Mi inconveniente se presenta al momento de querer obtener el valor seleccionado en el dropdownlist una vez dado clic sobre el control `HyperLinkField` me esta llegando el mismo valor siempre y no es el valor que yo selecciono

En el load establezco una validación para determinar si se va a realizar un proceso con los registros del datagrid o por si el contrario no se haran acciones

```
if (Request.QueryString["proceso"] != null)
 {
  decimal bodVenta = Convert.ToDecimal(DropDownListBodega.SelectedValue);// en este punto el valor siempre me llega igual
}
```

Requiero que me orienten un poco o lo que debo modificar para que no me llega el valor defecto si no el que yo selecciono

Comment: pero el HyperLinkField esta navegando a una pagina aspx diferente a donde tienes el DropDownList, salvo que lo envies como parte de los parametros de la url, no vas a poder obtener la seleccion accediando directo al combo

Comment: quizas en lugar de un HyperLinkField debas poner un CommandName que ejecute un evento RowCommand en la misma pagina para asi acceder al DropDownList y despues desde alli realizar el redirect a la otra pagina

Comment: leandro muchas gracias por responder, el HyperLinkField tiene una dirección pero es a la misma pagina, solo que toma unos parámetros de la consulta que empleo para llenar el datagrid

Comment: pero estas navegando a la misma pagina, por lo tanto se vuelve a recargar el DropDownList  perdiendo la seleccion

Comment: si podria ser, como podria evitar que se pierda el valor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para tomar el valor del `DropDownList` tendrias que usar el evento `RowCommand`

[Using CommandField in a GridView control](https://vkinfotek.com/gridview/gridview-commandfield.html)

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewDatos" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" DataKeyNames="id_factura,id_detalle_factura,id_factura_articulo" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="id_factura_articulo" HeaderText="Id Factura Articulo" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="id_factura" HeaderText="ID Factura" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="id_detalle_factura" HeaderText="Detalle Factura" /> 
    <asp:BoundField DataField="nombre_articulo" HeaderText="Nombre Articulo" /> 
    <asp:BoundField DataField="nombre_bodega" HeaderText="Bodega" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="serial" HeaderText="Serial" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="codigobarras" HeaderText="Código Barras" />
    ButtonType="Link" ShowSelectButton ="true"  />
</Columns>
```

especial atencion al `<asp:BoundField`

[CommandField.ShowSelectButton Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandfield.showselectbutton?view=netframework-4.5)

ya que luego usaras el evento

```
void GridViewDatos_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridViewDatos.SelectedRow;

    string id_factura = GridViewDatos.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["id_factura"];
    string id_detalle_factura = GridViewDatos.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["id_detalle_factura"];
    //resto

    decimal bodVenta = Convert.ToDecimal(DropDownListBodega.SelectedValue);

}
```

alli si vas a poder acceder al valor del combo porque se dio en un evento de la pagina y no en una navegacion de un link

Comment: a que hace referencia index en esta linea? `string id_detalle_factura = GridViewDatos.DataKeys[index].Values["id_detalle_factura"];` nombre de la pagina?

Comment: edite el codigo agregando de donde se obtiene el index